# test accuracy fluctuate even train and test are always same

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Even though my train, validation and test set are always the same, test accuracy fluctuate. The only reason I can think of is weight initialization. I am using PyTorch and I guess they use advance initialization technique (kaiming initialization).

What might be the reason for accuracy fluctuation even though train, validation and test data are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to weight initialisation, dropout between layers also involves randomness and these can lead to different results on running again.

These random numbers are generally based on a seed value and fixing it can help reproduce the results. You can take a look [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) on how to fix seed value.

Comment: I want to optimize the hyper-parameters. do you think it is a good idea to fix the seed for all RNG ( by using torch.manual_seed(0) ) and then search for values of hyperparameters?

Comment: Yeah, I would suggest so in order to get consistent results. In general, your results should not be affected much by these random things like initialization.